# Using external libraries with ocamlbuild

Tags: makefile, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I'm trying to use `ocamlbuild` instead of `make`, but I'm unable to correctly link my object files with external `.cma` libraries. It seems like `ocamlbuild` tries to determine dependencies first and then ignores flags like `-L/path/to/lib.cma`. With `make` I was just passing all necessary directories with `-I` and `-L` flags to `ocamlc`, but these don't seem to work with `ocamlbuild` -- `ocamlc` keeps failing because it can't find necessary libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have at least 2 ways to pass your parameters to ocamlbuild for it to take your library in account:

1. You can use the command line parameters of ocamlbuild:

   ```
   $ ocamlbuild -cflags '-I /path/to/mylibrary' -lflags '-I /path/to/mylibrary mylibrary.cma' myprogram.byte
   ```

   Replace `.cma` by `.cmxa` for a native executable.
2. Use the myocamlbuild.ml file to let ocamlbuild "know" about the library, and tag the files which need it in the _tag file:

   In `myocamlbuild.ml`:

   ```
   open Ocamlbuild_plugin
   open Command

   dispatch begin function
     | After_rules ->
          ocaml_lib ~extern:true ~dir:"/path/to/mylibrary" "mylibrary"
     | _ -> ()
   ```

   In `_tags` :

   ```
   <glob pattern>: use_mylibrary
   ```

   The `ocaml_lib` instruction in `myocamlbuild.ml` tells the tool that the library named "mylibrary" (with specific implementations ending in `.cma` or `.cmxa` or others - profiling, plugins) is located in the directory "/path/to/mylibrary".

   All the files corresponding to `glob pattern` in the project directory will be associated to the use of "mylibrary" by `ocamlbuild`, and compiled with the ad hoc parameters (so you don't need to worry about native or byte targets).
   Ex:

   ```
   <src/somefile.ml>: use_mylibrary
   ```

Note: if the library is located in the path known by the compiler (usually `/usr/lib/ocaml` or `/usr/local/lib/ocaml`), then the path prefix can be safely replaced by a `+` sign, so `/usr/lib/ocaml/mylibrary` becomes `+mylibrary`.